# how to use icofont in html-css project?

Tags: html, css, icons

After extracting the zip file you will find a .ttf file inside the fonts folder. You should be able to install the font by double clicking on the .ttf file. Now, go to the IcoFont website, copy the icon you need to use and paste it in your graphic softwares (including Sketch, Photoshop or Illustrator). Please note, when you paste the icon, you need to have Type tool selected. After pasting the icon, select it, and then change the font family to “Icofont”.

i cannot understand this line.

Answer (score -1):

The instructions you provided are guiding you through the process of using a specific font file (.ttf file) and integrating it into your graphic design software (such as Sketch, Photoshop, or Illustrator) for use with icons from the IcoFont website.

Let's break down the steps:

Extract the Zip File: You have a zip file that contains various files, including a fonts folder. You need to extract the contents of this zip file.

Install the Font: Inside the extracted fonts folder, there should be a .ttf (TrueType Font) file. You install this font on your system by double-clicking on the .ttf file. This action should prompt your operating system to install the font, making it available for use in your graphic design software.

Copy the Icon: Visit the IcoFont website and find the icon you want to use. Once you've found the icon, you need to copy it. This usually involves selecting the icon and using the copy function (Ctrl+C on Windows or Command+C on macOS).

Paste the Icon: In your graphic design software (like Sketch, Photoshop, or Illustrator), open the document where you want to use the icon. Make sure you have the Type tool selected (the tool used for working with text). Then, paste the icon into your document using the paste function (Ctrl+V on Windows or Command+V on macOS).

Select and Change the Font Family: After pasting the icon, you need to select it using your software's selection tools. Once the icon is selected, you'll need to change the font family to "Icofont." This ensures that the icon is rendered using the IcoFont font you installed earlier.

By following these steps, you should be able to integrate icons from the IcoFont website into your graphic design projects using your preferred software.